# Adding a NuGet package to packages.config not associated with a Visual Studio project

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

In the limited amount of time I've worked with NuGet, the `packages.config` files I've encountered have all been associated with a Visual Studio project. I've just found one that seems to not be associated with a project (in this case a C# project). Rather, it's purpose appears to be to gather tools that are required to successfully complete a build of the solution the project is a component of (i.e. the NuGet packages in the `packages.config` file are never referenced directly in a .cs file).

I know I can open the `packages.config` in a text editor and add a new package to it. However, that seems to run contrary to the idea of NuGet as I understand it, and I'm not sure if adding an entry into `packages.config` manually won't create problems down the road.

What is the best way to add a new NuGet package to a `packages.config` file that's not associated with a Visual Studio project like this? The Microsoft docs I've found so far all seem to mention a corresponding VS project ( see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/ways-to-install-a-package)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Visual Studio to manage NuGet references for .NET projects that use packages.config is useful/important because of all the extra things that need to happen on "install". But for .NET projects that use PackageReference, using Visual Studio is just a minor convenience because it will restore the packages at the same time as changing the XML. There is no Visual Studio UI for isolated packages.config files

So, there's no problems editing your packages.config file with a text editor. You'll just need to run `nuget.exe restore` yourself (or more likely it's part of a build script). In fact, the NuGet team [have one themselves](https://github.com/NuGet/NuGet.Client/blob/dev/.nuget/packages.config) as part of their build.